# How to dynamically change change DI using autofac?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, repository-pattern

We are developing windows service, and i want to change `dbcontext` class dynamically in repositories.

bellow is the scenario.

I have three db context classes

```
 public abstract class Context : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
    {
        protected Context(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
        {

        }
    }

    public class PlatformContext : Context
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;

        public PlatformContext(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
            _connectionString = connectionString;
        }
    }

    public class PlatformReplicaContext : Context
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;
        public PlatformReplicaContext(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
            _connectionString = connectionString;
        }
    }

    public class TempContext : Context
    {
         private readonly string _connectionString;
         public TempContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
         {
           _connectionString = connectionString;
         }
   }
```

and i have repository

```
public interface ICategoryRepository : IRepository<Category>
   {

   }

 public class CategoryRepository :Repository<Category>, ICategoryRepository
   {
        public CategoryRepository(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }
   }
```

hence im using CQRS i have another three classes

```
public class CategoryBasicQuery:IRequest<BaseQueryResponse>
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryBasicQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<CategoryBasicQuery, BaseQueryResponse>
{
    private readonly ICategoryRepository _categoryRepository;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public CategoryBasicQueryHandler(ICategoryRepository categoryRepository, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
    public async Task<BaseQueryResponse> Handle(CategoryBasicQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var entry = await _categoryRepository.FindAsync(request.CategoryId);
        if (entry == null)
        {
            return new NotFoundResponse();
        }

        var response = _mapper.Map<CategoryBasicResponse>(entry);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Now here is the issue

Here category repository should be able to execute queries in all 3 types of contexts.
but how should i register classes in using autofac?
then i came up with a solution generating repositories in run time as below

```
public class RepositoryFactory
{
    public static TRepository GetRepositoryInstance<T, TRepository>(
        params object[] args)
        where TRepository : IRepository<T>
    {
        return (TRepository)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TRepository), args);
    }
}
```

im calling this method inside  `CategoryBasicQueryHandler` class like this

```
 var categoryRepo = RepositoryFactory.GetRepositoryInstance<Category, CategoryRepository>(new PlatformReplicaContext("connectionString"));
```

but when calling from CQRS

```
var categoty = new Category();
var command = new CategoryBasicQuery {CategoryId = categoryId};
var result =  _mediator.Send(command);
```

VS give me following error

[image]

and my autofac registration as follows

```
    builder.RegisterType<CategoryService>().AsSelf();
    builder.RegisterType<ActionRepository>().As<IActionRepository>();
    builder.RegisterType<CategoryRepository>().As<ICategoryRepository>();
    builder.RegisterType<Mapper>().As<IMapper>();
```

can anyone help me resolve this or suggest good method to handle this situation.

thanks.

Comment: By the way....`DbContext` is already a _unit of work_ so `IUnitOfWork` doesn't add anything

Comment: Didn't get your point?

Comment: 1) I don't see the point in creating an _abstract_ context from a concrete `DbContext` type.   2)  `DbContext` is already an implementation of the _unit of work_ pattern so there is no work for `Context` or derived types to do so stating `IUnitOfWork` is kinda redundant

Comment: @Roshan - well, there are several ways of doing that. The question is - what is the condition that determines which context to use? Solution will depend on it.

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov -  we can depend on a variable , say there is variable called action and if action is something use different context , issue is i cant imaging how to integrate this variable.

Comment: You're trying to describe solution. What is the meaning of that variable? Where would its value come from? What would its value be? Where do you think to place it? See - just saying "it's going to be a variable" does not clarify anything. Besides, placing a variable is already a solution while what I ask you about is a problem itself. Why do you need to switch contexts in the first place?

Comment: @AlexanderLeonov - i need switch context because as an example i have a method saveCategory() and i need to use this method to save category in db1 as well as db2 this is why i need to switch context.value is comes from a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may give you a good starting point for a possible solution: http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#keyed-service-lookup-iindex-x-b

```
builder.RegisterType<PlatformContext>().Keyed<Context>("platform");
builder.RegisterType<PlatformReplicaContext>().Keyed<Context>("replica");
builder.RegisterType<TempContext>().Keyed<Context>("temp");
```

You mentioned in a comment that there is a variable named `action` somewhere that will indicate which implementation to use:

```
public class Class1
{
    private readonly IIndex<string, Context> contexts;

    public Class1(IIndex<string, Context> contexts)
    {
         this.contexts = contexts;
    }

    public void Whatever()
    {
        string action = ...; // platform, replica or temp
        Context context = this.contexts[action];
        ...
    }
}
```

Of course this needs to be adapted so that it will fit in the rest of your application design. A possible example could be:

```
Context context = this.contexts[action];

using(ILifetimeScope scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(builder =>
{
    builder.RegisterInstance(context).As<Context>();
}))
{
    // Because we are resolving IMediator from the scope, the selected Context will be used in all dependencies
    var mediator = scope.Resolve<IMediator>();
    mediator.Send(...);
}
```